# How to pass Javascript object from one script to another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ecmascript-6, typescript

I am developing two WordPress plugins one being free version and another being Premium. Here, I would like to use the methods of script from the Free version in the Premium Version. I had initially thought of using `Costum Event` to pass the Javascript object from the Free version so that catching the event, I could use the methods[modules] inside the Object. But the Event Listener is not listening to the Costum Events that was dispatched from Script in the Free version of the plugin.

Comment: You don't really pass it to another script, but script tags below have access to code in the script tags above, as long as it's top level scoped code.

Comment: What if the script is written in modular pattern, the modules are not accessible? I have also tried from the console to see if the methods are available or not, and the methods were not accessible.

Comment: If you made or have access to the Modules, make sure you have access to the variables. Like put them above jQuery load code and things that scope them off. Make sure you don't scope them off below.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I assume you don't have freedom of updating free version plugin. If javascript in free version is not exposed in global scope or if it doesn't have desired event listeners then you need to replace it by dequeuing the javascript handler of free version and enquing modified version from your premium plugin.

Comment: But then, We need the same script to be able to use for other features that is only included in the free version. So I think, I have to keep the script in the free version. The only issue here is I want to extend the modules that are available in the free version to be able to use them in the premium version as it also requires to change some behaviours in the premium version.

Comment: If new javascript file enqueued in premium version is a slightly modified version of free plugin javascript then both should work.